# Why is my random vector generator creating NaN vectors when I call a seemingly unrelated function on setup?

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, computational-geometry

I'm making an algorithm that involves generating a cloud of random points in P5.js. Here is my function:

```
function generatePoints(amount) {
  function generatePoints(amount) {
  let points = []
  for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let px = int(random(-width/4, width/4))
    let py = int(random(-height/4, height/4))
    print(px, py)
    let myPoint = createVector(px, py)
    print(myPoint)
    circle(px, py, 3)
    points.push(myPoint)
  }
  }
  return points
}
```

And i have `setup()` like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  translate(offsetX,offsetY)
  background(220)
  let points = generatePoints(10)
  let hull = drawConvexHull(points)
  print(hull)
  //smallestRectColEdge(hull)
}
```

However if i uncomment the last line from `setup()`, some of the points become vectors with NaN as their x and y values, and I have no idea why! `smallestRectColEdge()` is supposed to find the smallest bounding rectangle of the convex hull of the cloud of generated points, and as far as I can tell there is nothing in its code that interacts with `generatePoints()`, so I'm stumped.

If it helps, here is a print of a `enter code here`random generation from `generatePoints()` when `smallestColRectEdge()` is uncommented

```
50 86
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: NaN, y: NaN…}
78 -32
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 78, y: -32…}
-51 -94
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: NaN, y: NaN…}
-70 -69
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -70, y: -69…}
90 -54
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: NaN, y: NaN…}
-98 -78
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: NaN, y: NaN…}
26 -11
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 26, y: -11…}
29 -71
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 29, y: -71…}
58 48
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 58, y: 48…}
13 -30
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 13, y: -30…}
```

Yet, when I comment `smallestRectColEdge`, everything seems fine. Here's a print of the program running with it commented.

```
16 -90
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 16, y: -90…}
-61 68
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -61, y: 68…}
99 -13
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 99, y: -13…}
-78 43
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -78, y: 43…}
-41 86
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -41, y: 86…}
81 -3
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 81, y: -3…}
-16 52
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -16, y: 52…}
92 90
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 92, y: 90…}
-31 52
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: -31, y: 52…}
97 63
_class {isPInst: true, _fromRadians: ƒ bound (), _toRadians: ƒ bound (), x: 97, y: 63…}
```

The problem isn't in `drawConvexHull()` either. With `smallestRectColEdge()` commented, I asked for it to print both the points array given as an argument and the points that became the hull, and not a NaN in sight. I have no idea how the problem could be in it, but by elimination it's the only place where it could be, so here is `smallestRectColEdge()`.

```
function smallestRectColEdge(hull){
  print(hull)
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  let angles = []
  let rotatedHulls = []
  let OBBs = []
  let smallestOBB
  
  //get all angles for rotating the hull
  for(let i = 0; i < hull.length; i++) {
    let angle = 0
    let diff = 0
    if(i < hull.length-1) {
      diff = p5.Vector.sub(hull[i+1], hull[i])
    } else {
      diff = p5.Vector.sub(hull[i], hull[0])
    }
    diff.normalize()
    angle = atan2(diff)
    
    let rotations = {
      rotAngle: angle,
      locAx: [diff, createVector(-diff.y, diff.x)]
    }
    
    angles.push(rotations)
  }
  
  //effectively rotating the hulls, and getting an OBB
  //out of each rotation
  
  for(i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
    let minX = 400
    let minY = 400
    let maxX = -400
    let maxY= -400
    let rotatedHull = [...hull]
    
    //rotating the hull
    rotatedHull.forEach((myPoint)=>{
      myPoint.rotate(angles[i].rotAngle)
    })
    
    //print(rotatedHull)
    
    //making the AABBs
    rotatedHull.forEach((myPoint)=>{
      if(minX > myPoint.x) {minX = myPoint.x}
      else if(maxX < myPoint.x) {maxX = myPoint.x}
      if(minY > myPoint.Y) {minY = myPoint.Y}
      else if(maxY < myPoint.y) {maxY = myPoint.y}
    })
    
    //print(minX, maxX, minY, maxY)
    
    let OBB = {
      mins: createVector(minX, minY),
      maxes: createVector(maxX, maxY),
      u: maxX-minX,
      v: maxY-minY,
      locAx: angles[i].locAx,
      area: (maxX-minX) * (maxY-minY)
    }
    
    //print(OBB)
    OBBs.push(OBB)
  }
```

Also here is a link for the [whole project](https://editor.p5js.org/BisDante/sketches/4x3APMLPa), if it's relevant.

It seems to have something to do with how the hull is being operated, since the amount of NaN vectors are equal to the points in the hull, but if that's the case should the print functions in `generatePoints()` print out NaNs at all, since points are supposedly becoming NaN at a function that is called later?

what was tried: generate a cloud of random points.
what happened: some points become NaN vectors.

edit: updated the code for having better debugging info and added `smallestRectColEdge()` code.

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all, like to check if the vector component values are turning up as `NaN` in the `generatePoints()` function?

Comment: if commenting out `smallestRectColEdge(hull)` fixes the issue, then something in `smallestRectColEdge` function is causing the issue ... at least you only need to debug one function

Comment: `here is a print of a random generation ...` is that with `smallestRectColEdge(hull)` commented out?

Comment: "Have you done any debugging at all, like to check if the vector component values are turning up as NaN in the generatePoints() function?"; Yes, I have, I ran it many times, and the component values generated by generatePoints() are never NaNs at all. They only become so after becoming part of a vector, weirdly enough.

">here is a print of a random generation ... is that with smallestRectColEdge(hull) commented out?"; No, it was uncommented, but I updated the question to have a debug test with it both commented and uncommented now.

Comment: Disable (i.e. comment out) parts of `smallestRectColEdge` functionality until the problem disappears. That way you should be able to narrow it down to a single line in there which makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are few gotchas in your `generatePoints` function:

```js
function generatePoints(amount) {
  function generatePoints(amount) {
  let points = []
  for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let px = int(random(-width/4, width/4))
    let py = int(random(-height/4, height/4))
    print(px, py)
    let myPoint = createVector(px, py)
    print(myPoint)
    circle(px, py, 3)
    points.push(myPoint)
  }
  }
  return points
}
```

- `function generatePoints(amount)` is repeated (nested): probably a typo
- in JS is best to avoid variable names name clashes (e.g. `points` / `POINTS`, etc.)
- if you're re-rendering points later on, probably the circle call is redundant

Here's a basic sketch with a refactored version of your function:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  // generate points
  const numPoints = 10;
  let randomPoints  = generatePoints(numPoints);
  
  // render points
  beginShape();
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  for(let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    const myPoint = randomPoints[i];
    vertex(myPoint.x, myPoint.y);
  }
  endShape();
}

function generatePoints(amount) {
  let myPoints = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let px = int(random(-width/4, width/4));
    let py = int(random(-height/4, height/4));
    let myPoint = createVector(px, py);
    myPoints.push(myPoint);
  }
  return myPoints;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This is even before looking into `smallestRectColEdge`.
It feels you might going too fast: sometimes slowing down counterintuively can speed you up. Try focusing on one function a time, testing it thoroughly with dummy data (even bad data to handle cases), then move to the next function. This way you'll have the confidence that what you've written so far works as expected and if/when a new problem arises it will be much easier to isolate the issue (since it will be most recently added code).

([`p5.Vector.random2D()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/random2D) might also be of interest)